# Некорректный скроллинг при DOMContentLoaded

Tags: javascript

Страница разбита на n суперблоков структуры:

```
суперблок
    блок
        картинка
```

При DOMContentLoaded должен происходить скроллинг к одному из суперблоков.
Из-за того, что при первоначальной загрузке страницы картинка не имеется в кэше, скроллинг некорректен.
Какие варианты исправления поведения возможны?

P.S.: window.onload не подходит, скроллинг к блоку не должен задерживаться

Comment: Попробуйте setTimeout с нулевой задержкой

Comment: Уже решил проблему.